# can't download ubuntu

Tags: downloads

I am unable to download ubuntu 13.04. the hosting site always claims the server is down and it has been like this since 10am GMT. any help guys? I really need this to install to my laptop as I prefer it substantially over windows 7

Comment: Problem seems to be on your end. I can download the ISO without a problem.

Comment: Try another mirror. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

Comment: From where do you try to download it?

Answer (score 1):

Like the other folks said, **try another mirror**.  I like to use **my closest, fastest mirror**:  http://mirror.cse.ucdavis.edu/releases.ubuntu.com/.